# Google Custom Search: Sort by Date not working?

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search

I'm trying to sort a Google Custom Search query by date as suggested in the GCS guide (by adding "&sort=date" to the query URL) but I cannot make it work (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#sort-by-attribute).

For a lengthy description of all my attempts check this post: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/jdyvGsJhqAw

Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

try sort=date:d:s

or for range you can use
sort=date:r:fromdate:todate

or for more information, go through 
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#using-page-dates

Hope it helps!